# Why is the last block in Hadoop Distributed File System is of different size than the others?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Each file in HDFS is stored as as a sequence of Blocks. Blocks are of equal sizes, except the last one. Why? Is is possible to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot change this behavior. The size and number of blocks corresponding to files depends on the configuration property `dfs.blocksize`

Eg : If you wanted to keep a file of size 130MB in HDFS, having block size as 64MB, then there will be 3 blocks created: First two blocks will be having size 64MB each and the size of third block will be 2MB.

If you wanted to make the size of the 3rd block the same as the first two, then usage will be wasted.